# Modifying some text in a Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I need to remove some text from a webpage after it's rendered. For example, code
`<p>Micro<link></link>soft</p>`
returns
`Microsoft`
and I want my app to find and remove the
`os`
so we get
`Microft`
.

Comment: Are you using Javascript for it? If so, `text = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML`, then `textReplaced = text.replace('so', '')`, then `document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = textReplaced`

Comment: @jpenna As far as I know, this method works with the source code, but not with the rendered text.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. Webview works like a browser to show you the website's content. Like we can't modify any website's data opening with Chrome browser, we can't modify text through just a webview.

Comment: What you mean "you can't modify data opening Chrome"? You can modify everything of a page using the dev tools...

Comment: That is a after-loading-page action. But without any background script, is it possible to change any data at runtime website loading?

Answer (score 0):

Check shouldInterceptRequest method for altering html before rendering in webview.

Here is my code which i use to block ad

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     @Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, @NonNull final WebResourceRequest request) {
    if (mAdBlock.isAd(request.getUrl().toString())) {
        ByteArrayInputStream EMPTY = new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes());
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "utf-8", EMPTY);
    }
}
}
```